# Rewriting output of View

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I have a View of taxonomies. I want to rewrite the output of each field (name) as this:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);" onClick="alert('[name]');">[name]</a>
```

so when I click on the taxonomy, it will prompt an alert with the term name.

I try to rewrite through the Views GUI to no avail.
I even tried with `views_pre_render`but because there is no #markup property, the rewriting is not HTML but plain text.
I did the trick with views_pre_render and other kind of content, but not in taxonomy. And is it really impossible to achieve that in the GUI ? Surely I am missing something very very basic here.

Comment: Do you mean the field label?

Comment: The field **Taxonomy term: Name** . I am reading many post in drupal.org about the case, and cannot believe my eyes. From recommending to use other extra modules, to use PHP Views (a.k.a. the insecure module), and still in 8 it seems the solution is not apparent. We are talking about something extremely basic.

Comment: I confirm that it should be a issue in views. But I understand why no one try to fix it. Drupal discourages using `onClick`. If you want to bind click event, you need to do it with [JS behaviors](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).

Comment: Yes, I suspected that. Or binding with jQuery, right? I will go that path. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through theming.

For that you can create a new **views-view-field--VIEW_NAME--FIELD_NAME.tpl.php** file and write the HTML output for the field.

Dont't forget to clear your cache after adding the file or you can do 'Rescan template files' inside your view.

Comment: I expected not to use tpl, but well, it works.